# Phonegap: How to submit iOS app to app store from macincloud?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've already built my app on phonegap. tested it and everything worked fine so I am happy to publish it.

so I created my `distribution certificates` and created the `.IPA` file and it is now ready to be submitted for review and publishing.

I don't have a mac machine but I have came across quite a few information about using  *macincloud* to submit the app to app store.

However, the issue that I have is that I have no idea what to do.

is there any clear instructions or tutorial on how to do this?

Please note that I have found quite a few tutorials about  macincloud but they are all about **CREATING** the app on  macincloud and **NOT** about just submitting it the app to app store!

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured it out.

I had to use `itunes connect` and `application up-loader` and the job was done.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for asking and answering this question. I also dived into the iOS development using phonegap. Want to know did you use the itunes connect and application up-loader in the MacinCloud or on Windows system to publish the app? I will appreciate any help from you. Thanks